# Calculated field not showing up in "New Item"

Tags: 2013, list, column

Is there any way to show a calculated field when I'm filling out a new item for a list?

For example:

If I select "Blue" in field1, and "Bird" in field2,

then, on the same page where I am filling in information, I can see field3(Calculated field) show a value of "Blue Jay"

Currently, the calculated field doesn't show until I add a new item.
It would be even better if the update was in real time, though I don't expect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As a short answer** : unfortunately , No, the calculated field is calculated after the item added or updated

If you are using Enterprise Edition of SharePoint then try editing list form with InfoPath and insert field which will do the calculation for you. Make that field read-only and then publish the form.

In InfoPath , You can

- Add a Textbox as `field3` in your form
- At `field2` add  new a `Action rule` and at **run these action select** `set a fields value`
- At **Field** Value select Field3
- At **Value** concatenate your `field1` and `field2`

[image]

Comment: I have InfoPath, but after I add the field, it's not showing the calculated value. Is there a way to get it to show information while the user is in the process of entering the information?

Comment: @TTRC So sorry for delay , please check my updated answer and don't hesitate to tell me if you need any calarafication

Answer (score 4):

Calculated columns don't work that way, they are visible on the display form only or in views and only recalculate when items are edited.

If you want that type of preview feature, you'll have to incorporate custom javascript on your forms.